# Codename One Font Image Generate from Web Source

Tags: image, codenameone

I am using the following example from the CN1 FontImage documentation:

```
Font materialFont = FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont();
int w = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
FontImage fntImage = FontImage.createFixed("\uE161", materialFont, 0xff0000, w, w);
```

The example uses a unicode image, but I want to import an icon from a web source like [fontello](https://fontello.com) . How do I generate a FontIamage from the downloaded icon?

I have also tried to modify the unicode entry "\uE161" from the example to "\u004D", what should return a [capital M](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+004D), but it just return a square ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have exact instructions to get the facebook logo from the [Build Real World Full Stack Mobile Apps in Java](https://codenameone.teachable.com/p/build-real-world-full-stack-mobile-apps-in-java) course. You need to use the right font object, the easiest way to do this is define an "IconFont" UIID in the designer and pick the fontello.ttf file for that font. Then just do something like:

```
Label icon = new Label("\uf308", "IconFont");
```

See this for the steps in defining fontello and getting the values you need:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who try to use icons from external sources in CN1 components, some additional - and hopefully helpful - info to importing from sites like [Fontello](http://fontello.com/), just completing Shai Almog's above perfect explanation :

Two sites are helpful :

1. The [FontImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/FontImage.html) documentation;
2. This Codename One [article](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-icon-fonts-such-as-fontello.html);

This code then worked for me:

```
    Font materialFont = Font.createTrueTypeFont("fontello", "fontello.ttf");        
    int w = 100;
    FontImage fntImage;
    fntImage = FontImage.createFixed("\ue801", materialFont, 0x000000, w, w);
```